# How to filter a dataframe by consecutive value and condition?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 3]})

>>> df
    a
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   1
5   3
6   1
7   1
8   4
9   4
10  5
11  5
12  5
13  6
14  6
15  3
```

I want to keep the repeated values in column 'a' that appear consecutively and are less than or equal 5.

That index of dataframe kept should be rows 0,1,2,6,7,8,9,10,11,12.

How to do this in a pythonnic way?

The result should like this:

```
    a
0   1
1   1
2   1
6   1
7   1
8   4
9   4
10  5
11  5
12  5
```

Comment: I see first group 3 times consecutive1, second group 2times consecutive1, third group 2times consecutive 4, fourth group 3times consecutive5 and last group 2 times consecutive 6. So not understand `I want to keep only those rows in columns 'a' with less than or equal 5 consecutive occurrences of the same values`

Comment: @jezrael Sorry for my bad english grammar, I mean the row what I want keep must occurs consecutive and the value must great than 5.

Comment: @skywave1980 then why do you drop the row index 3? or 4? or 13/14?

Comment: I really don't know what you're asking. Please remember the number of downvotes of this question. Clarity is a virtue that must be possessed in question.

Comment: @skywave1980 I updated the English based on what you described in the comments, please make sure this is the intended meaning.

Comment: @mozway beacuse index 3, 4 and their shift value do not appear consecutively. And 13/14's value great than 5.

Comment: @skywave1980 it's clear now, thanks

Comment: @mozway, Sorry again for my bad expression.

Comment: @PandaKim Sorry for my bad description, I modified the question to make it more clearer, hope it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html), but in your case it looks like you rather want to filter the groups at least 2 values and no more than 5 as value:

```
# consecutive values
m1 = df.groupby(df['a'].ne(df['a'].shift()).cumsum()).transform('size').gt(1)
# less or equal to 5
m2 = df['a'].le(5)

out = df[m1&m2]
```

Or without [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) but using [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
# consecutive values
m0 = df['a'].diff().eq(0)
m1 = m0|m0.shift(-1)

# less or equal to 5
m2 = df['a'].le(5)

out = df[m1&m2]
```

Output:

```
    a
0   1
1   1
2   1
6   1
7   1
8   4
9   4
10  5
11  5
12  5
```

##### Intermediates:

###### first approach

- `m1`: consecutive values
- `m2`: values lower or equal to 5

```
    a     m1     m2
0   1   True   True
1   1   True   True
2   1   True   True
3   2  False   True
4   1  False   True
5   3  False   True
6   1   True   True
7   1   True   True
8   4   True   True
9   4   True   True
10  5   True   True
11  5   True   True
12  5   True   True
13  6   True  False
14  6   True  False
15  3  False   True
```

###### second approach

- `m0`: same a previous value
- `m1`: same a previous or next value
- `m2`: equal or less than 5

```
    a     m0     m1     m2
0   1  False   True   True
1   1   True   True   True
2   1   True   True   True
3   2  False  False   True
4   1  False  False   True
5   3  False  False   True
6   1  False   True   True
7   1   True   True   True
8   4  False   True   True
9   4   True   True   True
10  5  False   True   True
11  5   True   True   True
12  5   True   True   True
13  6  False   True  False
14  6   True   True  False
15  3  False  False   True
```

Comment: Thank you, the first answer is very close to my request, but the "6" in the last two lines should not be retained.

Comment: @skywave1980 I updated the answer based on your comment. SO you have 2 conditions, duplicated consecutive values AND no more than 5?

Comment: @skywave1980 I added another approach with `shift`

Comment: No problem, very clear and pythonic.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @mozway's [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/c0ae2de7-a17f-40d0-87b1-feb8cfc946d5/view-source), here is another possible option with [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html)/[`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) :

```
s = df["a"].mask(df["a"].gt(5))

out = df.loc[s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum().duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Output :

```
print(out)

    a
0   1
1   1
2   1
6   1
7   1
8   4
9   4
10  5
11  5
12  5
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter consetive values with less values like `5` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = df['a'].ne(df['a'].shift()).cumsum()
out = df[s.map(s.value_counts()).gt(1) & df['a'].le(5)]
print (out)

    a
0   1
1   1
2   1
6   1
7   1
8   4
9   4
10  5
11  5
12  5
```

Answer (score 1):

I also wrote a bit of ugly code that worked too. But it's not pythonic at all.

```
>>> df[((df.a == df.a.shift())|(df.a == df.a.shift(-1)))&(df.a.le(5))]
    a
0   1
1   1
2   1
6   1
7   1
8   4
9   4
10  5
11  5
12  5

>>> df[(df.a.diff().eq(0)|df.a.diff(-1).eq(0))&df.a.le(5)]
    a
0   1
1   1
2   1
6   1
7   1
8   4
9   4
10  5
11  5
12  5
```

I Used .eq instead of == according @mozway's suggestion.

Comment: It's actually similar to my second approach, I just compute a boolean and shift it backwards. Here you compute it twice (in both directions). I don't think it's not pythonic, at least it's explicit. You can use `.eq` in place of `==` and remove the parenthesis to improve readability.

Comment: @mozway Yes they are very similar, use .eq and .ne is good idea. Thanks for you comment and time.